# Can you explain this possible anomaly in position:absolute property?

Tags: html, css, image

I have extracted the following from a project im working on :
https://jsfiddle.net/x5oq3be6/

the image that i expect to be below is showing up above the the other image 
is this normal ?

in the code

```
<div id="container">
<img id="window" src="https://i.imgur.com/pfMrcLo.png" alt="">
<img id="slider" src="https://i.imgur.com/bT9byOg.png" alt="">

</div>
```

and css

```
#container{
  position:relative;
}
#window,#slider{
  position:absolute;


}

#slider{
  top:-40px;
}
```

window is above the slider 
however window is showing up below the slider

what could be the reason?

thank you

Comment: `window is above the slider ` --> The browser read the html from top to bottom. being the first on the code doesn't mean being on the top. it's the opposite (if of course there is no z-index or other properties involved). https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#painting-order

Answer (score 2):

As Temani said, the browser reads the HTML top to bottom. Here is an example on your question on different order of the images. https://jsfiddle.net/L8ez6h5p/7/

Example:

```
<img id="window" src="https://i.imgur.com/pfMrcLo.png" alt="">
<img id="slider" src="https://i.imgur.com/bT9byOg.png" alt="">
```

Versus

```
<img id="slider" src="https://i.imgur.com/bT9byOg.png" alt="">
<img id="window" src="https://i.imgur.com/pfMrcLo.png" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of loading or work with `z-index`

```
#window {
  z-index: 1;
}
#slider {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`position` attribute in css only change the position of the element in **x and y axis**.If you want to change the position of element in z direction. use `z-index`, higher the value of `z-index` element come above the other element.

Answer (score 0):

what I make out of all the answers is the following

1.the browser reads the html document from top to bottom 
2. as it reads the first coded element -> it places it on the screen first 
3. then the next coded element is placed on top of the already placed element.

So if we want element A on top of element B:
one way to do it is  to code B first then code A. Because browser will read B and place it first the read A and place it on the top.